# Crop imageButton in the shape of the background android

Tags: android, crop, shadow, android-vectordrawable, android-imagebutton

[image]

As you can see in the image, the `ImageButton` has the background of a "settings icon" but it's considered a rectangle. I want it to be cropped in the shape of the icon so the ripple effect will be only on the icon itself and won't continue outside of the icon bounds (like in [this tutorial](https://blog.stylingandroid.com/ripples-part-2/) (fourth Ex) but with the custom shape).
(the same problem appears for using `elevation` which makes the shadow to be rectangular and not around the background).
How can I achieve it?

My code:

```
  <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
  tools:context=".MainActivity">

  <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:outlineProvider="background"

        android:background="@drawable/ic_settings_black_24dp"
        android:backgroundTint="#c0c0c0"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

`ic_settings_black_24dp.xml` (from Vector Asset Studio):

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:width="24dp"
        android:height="24dp"
        android:viewportWidth="24"

        android:viewportHeight="24">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#fff"
        android:pathData="M19.1,12.9a2.8,2.8 0,0 0,0.1 -0.9,2.8 2.8,0 0,0 -0.1,-0.9l2.1,-1.6a0.7,0.7 0,0 0,0.1 -0.6L19.4,5.5a0.7,0.7 0,0 0,-0.6 -0.2l-2.4,1a6.5,6.5 0,0 0,-1.6 -0.9l-0.4,-2.6a0.5,0.5 0,0 0,-0.5 -0.4H10.1a0.5,0.5 0,0 0,-0.5 0.4L9.3,5.4a5.6,5.6 0,0 0,-1.7 0.9l-2.4,-1a0.4,0.4 0,0 0,-0.5 0.2l-2,3.4c-0.1,0.2 0,0.4 0.2,0.6l2,1.6a2.8,2.8 0,0 0,-0.1 0.9,2.8 2.8,0 0,0 0.1,0.9L2.8,14.5a0.7,0.7 0,0 0,-0.1 0.6l1.9,3.4a0.7,0.7 0,0 0,0.6 0.2l2.4,-1a6.5,6.5 0,0 0,1.6 0.9l0.4,2.6a0.5,0.5 0,0 0,0.5 0.4h3.8a0.5,0.5 0,0 0,0.5 -0.4l0.3,-2.6a5.6,5.6 0,0 0,1.7 -0.9l2.4,1a0.4,0.4 0,0 0,0.5 -0.2l2,-3.4c0.1,-0.2 0,-0.4 -0.2,-0.6ZM12,15.6A3.6,3.6 0,1 1,15.6 12,3.6 3.6,0 0,1 12,15.6Z"/>
</vector>
```

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set your vector as item in ripple effect resource

`ic_settings_black_24dp.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24"
    android:viewportHeight="24">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#c0c0c0"
        android:pathData="M19.1,12.9a2.8,2.8 0,0 0,0.1 -0.9,2.8 2.8,0 0,0 -0.1,-0.9l2.1,-1.6a0.7,0.7 0,0 0,0.1 -0.6L19.4,5.5a0.7,0.7 0,0 0,-0.6 -0.2l-2.4,1a6.5,6.5 0,0 0,-1.6 -0.9l-0.4,-2.6a0.5,0.5 0,0 0,-0.5 -0.4H10.1a0.5,0.5 0,0 0,-0.5 0.4L9.3,5.4a5.6,5.6 0,0 0,-1.7 0.9l-2.4,-1a0.4,0.4 0,0 0,-0.5 0.2l-2,3.4c-0.1,0.2 0,0.4 0.2,0.6l2,1.6a2.8,2.8 0,0 0,-0.1 0.9,2.8 2.8,0 0,0 0.1,0.9L2.8,14.5a0.7,0.7 0,0 0,-0.1 0.6l1.9,3.4a0.7,0.7 0,0 0,0.6 0.2l2.4,-1a6.5,6.5 0,0 0,1.6 0.9l0.4,2.6a0.5,0.5 0,0 0,0.5 0.4h3.8a0.5,0.5 0,0 0,0.5 -0.4l0.3,-2.6a5.6,5.6 0,0 0,1.7 -0.9l2.4,1a0.4,0.4 0,0 0,0.5 -0.2l2,-3.4c0.1,-0.2 0,-0.4 -0.2,-0.6ZM12,15.6A3.6,3.6 0,1 1,15.6 12,3.6 3.6,0 0,1 12,15.6Z"/>

</vector>
```

You can set ripple effect color here
`ripple_settings.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="#fff000" // set Color of ripple effect
    android:exitFadeDuration="500">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_settings_black_24dp" />
</ripple>
```

`activity_main.xml`

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_settings_black_24dp"
        android:foreground="@drawable/ripple_settings"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks! worked like a charm. I just wondered why didn't it work with `android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"`

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of trying I think I got the effect you asked for.

First we need to define a custom ripple effect by creating a new file in the drawable directory. I named it `ripple_ic_settings`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- The color here is the color of the ripple effect. I set it to teal to see the effect better. -->
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="@color/teal_700"
    android:exitFadeDuration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime">
    <!-- The drawable must be set to your vector icon. In this case the settings icon -->
    <item android:id="@android:id/mask" android:drawable="@drawable/ic_settings_black_24dp">
        <!-- The shape of the ripple effect -->
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <corners android:radius="3dp"/>
            <solid android:color="@android:color/white"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <!-- Color is set to transparent so we dont see the background -->
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</ripple>
```

On the first `item` entry we set the `android:drawable` attribute to the vector icon drawable. You can set this to any vector icon you like but keep in mind you need to create this custom ripple effect for every icon you want to use in your app.

Than I modified your `ic_settings_black_24dp.xml` like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24"

    android:viewportHeight="24">
    <!-- fillColor is the color that you want for your icon -->
    <path
        android:fillColor="#c0c0c0"
        android:pathData="M19.1,12.9a2.8,2.8 0,0 0,0.1 -0.9,2.8 2.8,0 0,0 -0.1,-0.9l2.1,-1.6a0.7,0.7 0,0 0,0.1 -0.6L19.4,5.5a0.7,0.7 0,0 0,-0.6 -0.2l-2.4,1a6.5,6.5 0,0 0,-1.6 -0.9l-0.4,-2.6a0.5,0.5 0,0 0,-0.5 -0.4H10.1a0.5,0.5 0,0 0,-0.5 0.4L9.3,5.4a5.6,5.6 0,0 0,-1.7 0.9l-2.4,-1a0.4,0.4 0,0 0,-0.5 0.2l-2,3.4c-0.1,0.2 0,0.4 0.2,0.6l2,1.6a2.8,2.8 0,0 0,-0.1 0.9,2.8 2.8,0 0,0 0.1,0.9L2.8,14.5a0.7,0.7 0,0 0,-0.1 0.6l1.9,3.4a0.7,0.7 0,0 0,0.6 0.2l2.4,-1a6.5,6.5 0,0 0,1.6 0.9l0.4,2.6a0.5,0.5 0,0 0,0.5 0.4h3.8a0.5,0.5 0,0 0,0.5 -0.4l0.3,-2.6a5.6,5.6 0,0 0,1.7 -0.9l2.4,1a0.4,0.4 0,0 0,0.5 -0.2l2,-3.4c0.1,-0.2 0,-0.4 -0.2,-0.6ZM12,15.6A3.6,3.6 0,1 1,15.6 12,3.6 3.6,0 0,1 12,15.6Z"/>

</vector>
```

I only changed the `fillColor` attribute on the `path` to the color you set the `backgroundTint` in your `ImageButton`.

Finally I changed the `ImageButton` in your layout to the following:

```
<ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_settings_black_24dp"
        android:foreground="@drawable/ripple_ic_settings"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

The important thing here is that you set the `android:background` to your icon (in this case `@drawable/ic_settings_black_24dp`) and the `android:foreground` to the custom ripple effect (`@drawable/ripple_ic_settings`).

Answer (score -1):

you can customise your button creating a selector in the drawables folder. mine is called button.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_enabled="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/button_disabled" />
    <item
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed" />
    <item
        android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/button_enabled" />
</selector>
```

You oviously have to create the different instances of your button by simply changing the color or transparency of the settings button i.e. you have to create `button_disabled.xml`, `button_pressed.xml` and `button_enabled.xml`. then you can pass button.xml it to your imageButton background property

```
android:background="@drawable/button"
```

and it should work.

Then there is the **lazy option ;)** if you actually like the background shade animation of the button but are simply anoyed by the ugly square that its projected into I suggest you try out the following code for your button:

```
 <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_settings_black_24dp"  //<---THIS IS KEY
        android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless" //<-- THIS IS KEY
        android:backgroundTint="#c0c0c0"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

Comment: this is not ripple it just changes the color when its pressed

Comment: well you are right, I just didnt think that would matter given the small size of your icon. but let me see if I find something that complies with what you need